# Tags - Gave X non-wiki answers with a total score of Y - Not accurate?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-score

So when I go to my profile I see:

[image]

When you click on the `88`, you are brought to a [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a682480%20%5bhtml%5d) with the **user:682480 [html]** as the search text.

That brings up:

[image]

As you can see there, there are `73` results and when non-wiki answers are totaled you get `95`.

So why does the profile only show `67` for `88`, when search shows `73` for `95`?

Comment: Some of those answers were posted in the last 24 hours - the system might only update your stats once a day.

Comment: Also, the search is too broad - it should have an `is:answer` filter. One of the 73 items is a question.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: the 5 most recent answers *would* have been included in the score (they are all from before midnight UTC yesterday), but the tag score script has failed again the past 3 days or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tag scores updating script has been failing to run again the last few days.

*Normally* it runs once a day around 03:00 UTC, but with the size of the Stack Overflow database this has been a intermittent problem of late.

See [Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse)

This affects tag scores, the awarding of expert badges, and the top 20 listings for each tag.

Comment: That makes total sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: I've looked into why the script was failing and the direct cause has been sorted. May take a couple of days to fully restore (as the zombie tag script needs to run before, in order for the update script to run to completion)

Comment: @Oded: \o/ I'll monitor it.